# How to make the download button for an audio file work?

Tags: html

Here is my html for the button, when clicked it does not download.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-md-right">
    <a href="/mp3/Ethereum.wav" class="btn-s uppercase btn btn-primary 
    with-ico" ><i class="icon-download"></i>Download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding `download` attribute to `<a>` tag, if it doesn't work you will have to opt javascript way.

Comment: Use `download="true"` attribute with your `anchor` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the download attribute, set it as `download="true"`

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-md-right">
    <a href="/mp3/Ethereum.wav" download="true" class="btn-s uppercase btn btn-primary 
    with-ico" ><i class="icon-download"></i>Download</a>
</div>
```